# List Item with NodeJS and Action-On-Google

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, node-modules, actions-on-google

I have a problem, 
I'm creating an app for google assistant, and I have to put items in a list, the problem is that I do not know how many elements the list contains.
The official documentation have an example on how to statically insert the elements into how I can donate them?
this is link documentation 
[https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#sample_code_7](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#list)
this is the example of the documentation

```
if (!conv.surface.capabilities.has('actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT')) {
  conv.ask('Sorry, try this on a screen device or select the ' +
    'phone surface in the simulator.');
  return;
}
// Create a list
conv.ask(new List({
  title: 'List Title',
  items: {
    // Add the first item to the list
    'SELECTION_KEY_ONE': {
      synonyms: [
        'synonym 1',
        'synonym 2',
        'synonym 3',
      ],
      title: 'Title of First List Item',
      description: 'This is a description of a list item.',
      image: new Image({
        url: 'IMG_URL_AOG.com',
        alt: 'Image alternate text',
      }),
    },
    // Add the second item to the list
    'SELECTION_KEY_GOOGLE_HOME': {
      synonyms: [
        'Google Home Assistant',
        'Assistant on the Google Home',
    ],
      title: 'Google Home',
      description: 'Google Home is a voice-activated speaker powered by ' +
        'the Google Assistant.',
      image: new Image({
        url: 'IMG_URL_GOOGLE_HOME.com',
        alt: 'Google Home',
      }),
    },
    // Add the third item to the list
    'SELECTION_KEY_GOOGLE_PIXEL': {
      synonyms: [
        'Google Pixel XL',
        'Pixel',
        'Pixel XL',
      ],
      title: 'Google Pixel',
      description: 'Pixel. Phone by Google.',
      image: new Image({
        url: 'IMG_URL_GOOGLE_PIXEL.com',
        alt: 'Google Pixel',
      }),
    },
  },
}));
```

in java would come like this, but in nodejs how can I do

```
//list with my data
List<Element> elements= new ArrayList<>();


List<ListSelectListItem> items = new ArrayList<>();
ListSelectListItem item;

for (Element _e : elements) {
   item = new ListSelectListItem();
   item.setTitle(_e.getTitele())
        .setDescription(_e.getDesctiprions())
        .setOptionInfo(
            new OptionInfo().setKey(_e.getKey())
        .setImage(
            new Image().setUrl(_e.getUrlImage());
    items.add(item);
}
```

I'm a Java developer and recently I'm learning NodeJS so I still have to understand some things, thanks in advance for the help

Comment: So you want to get the index of the list item?

Answer (score 0):

You can use similar principles to generate a list and send it out, as shown below. You may need to make specific affordances to get your data into a format that could be adapted to your Action.

```
const listItems = {};
// Let's say we already have an array
ourArray.forEach(item => {
  listItems[item.key] = {
    synonyms: item.synonyms,
    title: item.title,
    description: item.description,
    image: new Image({
      url: item.imageUrl,
      alt: item.imageAlt,
    }),
  }
});

conv.ask(new List({
  title: 'List Title',
  items: listItems
}));
```